# Vue.js component does not show up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, components, export

I'm having difficulties understanding where the problem is.

I have a component called `PlayerTabs` which has different tabs. One of them is Goals (Basketball). I want the component `BasketballGoals.vue` to appear in this tab.

[image: Here are the tabs]

In the component PlayerTabs I define the tabs in the template:

```
  <v-tab title="Goals (Basketball)">
    <app-basketball-goals></app-basketball-goals>
  </v-tab>
```

and import the component in the script:

```
import BasketballGoals from "./PlayerBasicInfo/BasketballGoals.vue";
```

and registered the BasketballGoals component `Playertabs` in components:

```
export default {
  components: {
    appPlayers: Players,
    appTimetables: Timetables,
    appHistories: Histories,
    appPhysicalGoals: PhysicalGoals,
    appBasketballGoals: BasketballGoals,
    appScholarship: Scholarship,
  },
```

The BasketballGoals component starts like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'goals',
        data: function() {
            return {
                times: [{
                    hour: '00',
                    isActive: false
                }, {
```

Here's the full [component](https://codeshare.io/aJ4zKr).

I've been trying for hours now to make the component appear in the tab, but I can't make it work and don't get an error too. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you registered `BasketballGoals` component `PlayerTabs` in `components` ?

Comment: @winiar Yes, see edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding component should go in `v-tab-item` element. Here is an example from the [tutorial](https://medium.com/vuetify/vuetiful-tabs-part-i-74ff5758e11e):

```
<v-tabs
  color="cyan"
  dark
  slider-color="yellow"
>
  <v-tab ripple>
    Item 1
  </v-tab>
  <v-tab ripple>
    Item 2
  </v-tab>
  <v-tab-item>
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>Contents for Item 1 go here</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
  <v-tab-item>
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>Contents for Item 2 go here</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>  
</v-tabs>
```

So, in your case:

```
<v-tab-item>
  <app-basketball-goals></app-basketball-goals>      
</v-tab-item>
```